# How to choose coefficients with scikit LinearRegression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, autoregressive-models

I want to find an autoregressive model on some data stored in a dataframe and I have 96 data points per day. The data is the value of solar irradiance in some region and I know it has a 1-day seasonality. I want to obtain a simple linear model using scikit LinearRegression and I want to specify which lagged data points to use. I would like to use the last 10 data points, plus the data point that has a lag of 97, which corresponds to the data point of 24 hour earlier. How can I specify the lagged coefficients that I want to use? I don't want to have 97 coefficients, I just want to use 11 of them: the previous 10 data points and the data point 97 positions back.

Comment: do you have any code or data to share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a dataset `X` with 11 columns `[x0-97, x0-10, x0-9,...,x0-1]`. Then series of `x0` will be your target `Y`.